# How do I most efficiently move, rename files and log this action?

Tags: powershell

I have the following CSV list (in reality 1000s of lines):

```
needle,code
123456,AB
121212,BB
33333333,CVV
```

And I have a directory (`C:\old_files`) containing PDF files (again, 1000s in reality):

```
dsadsadsa.343222.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
dsadsadsa.123456.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
dsadsadsa.111111.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
dsadsadsa.33333333.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
dsadsadsa.33333333.fsdgdsfdsfdsf.dsad.pdf
```

For each needle in the CSV:

- I have to see if there is a PDF containing that needle (there might be 0 or more matches)
- If there is a match, I have to

  1. make a copy of the file into a separate folder (`D:\new_files`)
  2. rename the copied file by prepending the respective code to the name
  3. write an entry into the log.

For the example, I have a match for `123456` and 2 for `33333333`, so I have to move a copy of these files into `D:\new_files` and rename them into:

```
AB.dsadsadsa.123456.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
CVV.dsadsadsa.33333333.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
CVV.dsadsadsa.33333333.fsdgdsfdsfdsf.dsad.pdf
```

The logfile would look like (format `needle,code,oldfilepath,newfilepath`):

```
123456,AB,C:\old_files\dsadsadsa.123456.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf,D:\new_files\AB.dsadsadsa.123456.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
33333333,CVV,C:\old_files\dsadsadsa.33333333.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf,D:\new_files\CVV.dsadsadsa.33333333.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
33333333,CVV,C:\old_files\dsadsadsa.33333333.fsdgdsfdsfdsf.dsad.pdf,D:\new_files\CVV.dsadsadsa.33333333.fsdgdsfdsfdsf.dsad.pdf
```

It is important that I only loop over the files in the directory once, because iterating through all files in a `ForEach` loop for each `needle` takes way too long. So with thanks to this forum I'm building a hashtable first:

```
$pairs = @{}
Import-CSV .\data.csv | ForEach-Object { $pairs[$_.needle] = $_.code+"." }

Get-ChildItem "C:\old_files" | Rename-Item -NewName { "D:\new_files\" + $pairs[$_.Name.Split('.')[1]] + $_.Name }
```

My first problem here: I am unable to move the file into the new folder.

**Q1** How do I properly copy a file from `C:\old_files` into `D:\new_files` and rename it?

My second problem: I don't understand how I can add code to the above code.

**Q2** How can I create the logfile for each match (and therefore: copied and renamed file)?

Comment: Please don't delete and re-post questions. Edit the question you already posted and be patient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually check if you have a match before copying the matching file.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\old_files" | ForEach-Object {
  $n = ($_.Name -split '.')[1]
  if ($pair[$n]) {
    $oldname = $_.FullName
    $newname = Join-Path 'C:\new_files' ($pair[$n] + $_.Name)
    Copy-Item $oldname $newname
  }
}
```

Do the logging after the copy operation:

```
Copy-Item $oldname $newname
if ($?) {
  # log success information here
} else {
  # log error information here
}
```